# Create date array

Tags: javascript

I have 2 dates: Start and End.
I need to create an array of dates with number of days between those 2 dates every 3 months.

Start = 8/19/2018
End = 11/19/2018

Array = [92,92,89,92,92]

[image: Example]

This is what i tried:

```
const start = "8/19/2018";
const end = "11/19/2018 ";

const dates = [];

const mstart = moment(new Date(start));
const mend = moment(new Date(end));

for (let i = 0; mstart < mend ; i++) {
    var Q = mstart.add(3, 'months').format( 'YYYY-MM-DD');
    const daysInMonth = startLease.diff(Q, 'days');
    dates.push(daysInMonth);
}
```

However, it returns array as 0.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly I am assuming from your screenshot that you meant 11/19/2019, not 2018. Also I assume in your code `startLease` is meant to be `mstart`?

With those assumptions, I believe the thing you are missing is that moment manipulation functions mutate the original moments, so saying `var Q = mstart.add(3, 'months')` also adds 3 months to `mstart`, so when you compare them you won't get the expected value, since they are both the same date. Instead you will need to make a clone of mstart, like this:

```js
const start = "8/19/2018";
const end = "11/19/2019 ";

const dates = [];

const mstart = moment(start, "MM/DD/YYYY");
const mend = moment(end, "MM/DD/YYYY");

while (mstart < mend) {
    let Q = mstart.clone();
    mstart.add(3, 'months');
    const daysInMonth = mstart.diff(Q, 'days');
    dates.push(daysInMonth);
}

console.log(dates);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes. This is exactly what i was looking for. Thank you so much!

Comment: How do i make the date range from 19th to 18th, instead of 19th to 19th? I tried .subtract(1,'days') however it won't give me the correct output for some months.

Comment: Changing `mstart.add(3, 'months')` to `mstart.add(3, 'months').subtract(1, 'days')` seems to work properly for me. What outputs are wrong? You'll also have to adjust the end date due to the `mstart < mend` check, otherwise you'll get an extra entry.

Answer (score 0):

We can do same by this.

```
const start = "8/19/2018";
const end = "11/19/2018 ";

const s = new Date(start)
const e = new Date(end)

const daysDifference = (e.getTime()-s.getTime())/1000/60/60/24  //finding diffeernce in milliseconds and then converting it to days

console.log(daysDifference) // required ans
```